# Concatenate function and shortcode to create a link in php

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, shortcode

I'm trying to create a link by concatenating the function `home_url()` and the short code `[pods field="audience_link"]` in PHP on top of WordPress. I have the code below in my PHP file but I'm getting a `500` error on running the code. Can someone please point out where I've gone wrong?

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() . '<?php echo do_shortcode('[pods field="audience_link"]' ); ?>'; ?> ">Testing Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening php tags within php tags is not a wise decision. Once you open and start php, you should not open any more until you close it off.

`<a href=" <?php echo home_url() . do_shortcode('[pods field="audience_link"]' ) ?> ">Testing Link</a>`